# Estimating R2 from a linear regression manually changing beta coefficient

Tags: r, lm

I want to know if there is a way to make a linear regression model and change the beta coefficient manually and estimate R2 after this change.

Simple example:

```
a <- c(2000 ,   2001  ,  2002  ,  2003 ,   2004)
b <- c(9.34 ,   8.50  ,  7.62  ,  6.93  ,  6.60)
c <- c(10.5 ,   12.8  ,  13.1  ,  14.4  ,  15.9)

fit=lm(a~b+c)
fit$coefficients
(Intercept)            b            c 
2005.1537642   -0.8948095    0.2866537 
summary(fit)$r.squared
[1] 0.9862912
```

I want to know what would be the R2 of this model if I used different betas for my variables "b" and "c".

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @Roland Trying a prediction model.

Comment: That doesn't explain anything. R-squared is usually not the measure of interest for a sensitivity analysis.

Comment: I think your comments are irrelevant to my post. I was just asking how to do something, not asking whether it's right or not. I wanted to know how to estimate an R2 with some betas coefficient and that's it. Thanks anyway for highlighting the sensitivity issue :).

Comment: It is of course your right to do whatever you want. In my experience giving a literal answer to a question is often not the best help. But to everyone their own. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the coefficient of determination by taking the square of the sample correlation coefficient between the outcomes and their predicted values:

```
cor(a, -0.8948095 * b + 0.2866537 * c) ** 2
## [1] 0.9862912
```

Just replace the coefficients from your linear model with the coefficients that you want to test.